# How to select query that one id is on the top and rest of them normal ordered

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want query that one id is on the top and others normal priority.

For Example: `ID 5` is on the top and others normal ordered.

```
ID  Name
-----------
5   Michael
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
6   E
```

What is the query of this in MS SQL?

Comment: how to not `scream` online?? turn off caps!!

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu: Dippas meant, do not use All CAPS in the question title, IT IS HARD TO READ THE POST.

Comment: got it, sorry then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement this slightly differently than the other answers here. Specifically, in the case where the ID could admit a value that's less than the chosen nonce, the ordering isn't correct. Here's an example:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *FROM (VALUES
        (5, 'Michael'),
        (1, 'A'),
        (2, 'B'),
        (3, 'C'),
        (4, 'D'),
        (-1, 'E')
    ) AS x(ID, Name)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN ID = 5 THEN 0 
      ELSE ID 
    END
```

Luckily for us, the fix is easy enough. We need to have full control over our arbitrary ordering column and then specify the secondary sort column. Like so:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *FROM (VALUES
        (5, 'Michael'),
        (1, 'A'),
        (2, 'B'),
        (3, 'C'),
        (4, 'D'),
        (-1, 'E')
    ) AS x(ID, Name)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN ID = 5 THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END,
   ID
```

Comment: i've just discovered this problem in my project and i saw this post.
thank you so much !

Comment: `var onlineUsers = onlineUsers.OrderBy(x => x.UserID == 5 ? 0 : 1).ThenByDescending(x => x.UserID).ToList();` i actually dont understand how it works. it is ordered by **OrderBy(x => x.UserID == 5 ? 0 : 1)** here. i got this. But **ThenByDescending(x => x.UserID)** i dont understand this field bcs they are ordering same column. it should order all records as DESC like 6,5,4,3,2,1. But it orders 5,6,4,3,2,1. this is what i want! but i dont understand this ordering :D

Comment: I often find it helpful to select all the things in cases like this. In this example, I'd do `SELECT CASE 
      WHEN ID = 5 THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END, *
FROM cte
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN ID = 5 THEN 0 
      ELSE 1 
    END,
   ID` just to look at the data. From there, it's just a normal sort on a compound key. Similar to how phone books are normally sorted by `(family name, given name)`).

Answer (score 5):

It's a conditional order by

```
select
   ID,
   Name
From 
   YourTable
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
      WHEN ID =5 THEN 0
      ELSE ID 
   END
```

Comment: that may have a problem with id 1

Comment: What if ID is integer? Implicit casts ahoy!

Comment: @Charleh what's your point? I'd sure hope ID was an integer... and even if it wasn't, the implicit cast wouldn't matter

Comment: Just thought it was a bit weird that you would use 0.5 and have an implicit cast rather than keeping the data types the same. You can get into trouble on larger tables doing casts like this (especially on data stored as varchar vs numeric etc)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from your_table
order by case when ID= '5' then 0 else ID end
```

Answer (score 2):

you case use case when in order by

```
Select * from yourtable
   order by case when id = 5 then 0 else Id end
   --instead of 0 you can provide any least number
```